# How to interactively shrink and grow Table View Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have cells in a table view in which users can select "show more" and the view can expand to show more detailed information. Conversely users can select "hide" and the view shrinks back to its original size.

Is this possible? Here a simplified version of what I have tried already for the expansion functionality:

Inside UITableViewCell:

```
//MARK: Views
let lbl: UILabel =  {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.text = "Initial text."
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0
    return lbl
}()

//MARK: Helper functions
func configureViewComponents() {
    selectionStyle = .none

    addSubview(lbl)
    lbl.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
}
```

Configuring the table view in my VC:

```
func configureViewComponents() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    
    tableView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0)
    tableView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
        
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    

    tableView.allowsSelection = true
    tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.register(EventCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "EventCell")
    
    
    view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView)
}
```

Delegate methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! EventCell
    //Do: expand functionality
    cell.lbl.text! += " aasdlfkajsdf;lksadj;flaskdfj;alskdjfa;sldkfj;alskdfj;asldkfjas;dlfkasjd;falskdfja;sdlkfajsd;flkasjdfl;askdf;jasldkfajs;dlfjak;sdasdf"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventCell", for: indexPath) as? EventCell {
        return cell
    }
    return EventCell()
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: “Is this possible?” Yes. “Am I missing something?” I don’t know. Maybe, how to do it?

Comment: @matt see the answer

Comment: I already have a way of doing it. See https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/331902ea2f30deb452271bcd82931c98777729b2/bk2ch08p451dynamicTableContent2/AccordionCell/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Although I am creating my views programmatically, you should set lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to TRUE. Also, call tableView.reloadData() after expanding the label's text.

Does anyone understand why these two are required to expand the cells height to fit the newly enlarged label?

Comment: Please don’t ask a question in the answer field.

Comment: @matt why? are we afraid it might help the community better understand the solution?

Comment: Because it's an answer, not a question. If you really still have a question, feel free to ask a new question (or edit the existing question). I mean, for example, I do know something about this, so I could reply, but now there is no place to do so.